# Apache2.4 mod_rewrite won't redirect me to subdir based on visiting domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress, apache-2.4

I have an Apache2.4 server with public dir in `/var/www/html`. In that dir I have a Wordpress site with this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

On the *same level* of the wp site there is a subdir with a RESTful API `/var/www/html/api/`

and a temporary landing page in `/var/www/html/temp/`

What I would like to achieve is:

- when user visits `mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com`, he should see the landing page in `temp` as it was the root
- when user visits the server with plain IP instead, he should see the wordpress blog (i.e. `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/` appears as the blog root) and should access the api the same way (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/...`)

I've tried many combinations in `.htaccess` such as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ temp [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

but to no result. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have access to server configuration, you should not use .htaccess as it [slows down your Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when). Also, it is much easier to handle this with two separated virtual hosts.

1) `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` (for IP and non-specified hostnames):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

2) `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com` for your example.com and www.example.com.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/temp
</VirtualHost>
```